# Entering a dummy row when query returns with no data

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, insert

I run a query which is used i excel. The data is updated once a week through a procedure. Some times the procedure returns with no data. In those cases I would like to add a dummy row with the date, so the users of the excel sees that there is no data for this date.

I have a column called TAG. It is tag 1-4. If tag 3 returns with no data, I would like to insert a row.

I just have a tmp-table. If it does not contain data for tag 3 I would like to add a dummy row with just a date but no data

```
CREATE procedure [dbo].[pr_quality_weekly]
as
begin   

insert into #tmp(date_run,country,tag,company,campaign,seller,orderdate,reg_date,enddate,cust_desc1,cust_desc2,phone_1,phone_2,delivery,reason,date_of_birth,product)

Select  * FROM prod_no
where date between datfrom and dateto

insert into #tmp(date_run,country,tag,company,campaign,seller,orderdate,reg_date,enddate,cust_desc1,cust_desc2,phone_1,phone_2,delivery,reason,date_of_birth,product)

Select  * FROM prod_se
where date between datfrom and dateto

Insert into prod_weekly (date_run,country,tag,company,campaign,seller,orderdate,reg_date,enddate,cust_desc1,cust_desc2,phone_1,phone_2,delivery,reason,date_of_birth,product)
(Select date_run,country,tag,company,campaign,seller,orderdate,reg_date,enddate,cust_desc1,cust_desc2,phone_1,phone_2,delivery,reason,date_of_birth,product 
from #tmp)

END
```

Comment: I just have a tmp-table. If it does not contain data for tag 3 I would like to add a dummy row with just a date but no data.

Comment: You need to actually add something here for us - *show us* the code you have written. Don't describe it to us in words... actually show us the code. (also don't put it in comments, the formatting is awful - edit your question and add it there.

Answer (score 0):

while i have no idea what your code is doing, creating that line could be simple but if you have `NOT NULL` columns in your prod weekly table, you'll have to provide empty strings as filler

```
Select date_run,country,days.tag,company,campaign
     , seller,orderdate,reg_date,enddate
     , cust_desc1,cust_desc2
     , phone_1,phone_2,delivery,reason,date_of_birth,product 
from (values (1),(2),(3),(4),(5)) days(tag)
left join #tmp on days.tag=#temp.tag
```